# Subharmonic functions inequality

Tags: proof-verification, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, maximum-principle

### The problem statement

Let $u\left( {x,y} \right),v\left( {x,y} \right)$ the solutions of the following problems:

$$\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
\Delta u = {e^{{x^2} + {y^2}}}{\rm{     \quad\quad          }}{x^2} + {y^2} < 1 \quad\quad\quad{\rm{           }}\\
{\left. u \right|_{{x^2} + {y^2} = 1}} = 1{\rm{  }}
\end{array} \right.\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
\Delta v = {e^{{x^2} + {y^2}}}{\rm{       \quad\quad        }}\left| x \right| + \left| y \right| < 1{\rm{ }}\\
{\left. v \right|_{\left| x \right| + \left| y \right| = 1}} = 1{\rm{  }}
\end{array} \right.$$
Prove that $u\left( {0,0} \right) < v\left( {0,0} \right)$

### My attempt:

First notice that $u\left( {x,y} \right)$ is sub harmonic in the unit disk and thus satisfies the maximum principle. 
As $u\left( {x,y} \right)$ is obviously not constant we can conclude that $u\left( {x,y} \right) < 1$ in the unit disk.

Next we define $w\left( {x,y} \right) = u\left( {x,y} \right) - v\left( {x,y} \right)$ and notice that:
$$\left\{ \matrix{
  \Delta w = 0{\rm{        \quad \quad       }}\left| x \right| + \left| y \right| < 1{\rm{ }} \hfill \cr 
  {\left. w \right|_{\left| x \right| + \left| y \right| = 1}} = {\left. u \right|_{\left| x \right| + \left| y \right| = 1}} - 1{\rm{  }} \hfill \cr}  \right.$$
From the previous paragraph we have that $${\left. w \right|_{\left| x \right| + \left| y \right| = 1}} = {\left. u \right|_{\left| x \right| + \left| y \right| = 1}} - 1 < 0{\rm{  }}$$
Since $w\left( {x,y} \right)$ is harmonic in $\left| x \right| + \left| y \right| < 1$ we get from the maximum principle:
$$w\left( {0,0} \right) < {\max _{\left| x \right| + \left| y \right| = 1}}w\left( {x,y} \right) < 0$$
and in conclusion:
$$u\left( {0,0} \right) < v\left( {0,0} \right)$$
$\blacksquare$

Is my solution correct?
I'd appreciate any kind of feedback.

Comment: I read it carefully and I think the reasoning works. Maybe the only thing I am not sure about is weather you really want to use the strong maximum principle at $w(0,0) < \max_{\dots} w(x,y)$ because "a priori" $w$ still could be constant? Even though the next line proofs it isn't I think here you would be fine with $w(0,0) \leq \max \dots$.

Comment: You're right, I missed that somehow. Thank you!